# Flex : Dimensions of an application

Tags: apache-flex, dimensions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init1()" width="100%">
<mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            public function init1():void
            {
                Alert.show(this.width.toString());
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

I am running the above code on a monitor with resolution 800x600. So, I expect
that the Alert that pops out will show the width to be 800. But it shows the width
to be 500. Why?

Comment: Perhaps too obvious, but just to be sure: is your application window maximized? Does it occupy the entire 800x600 screen?

Comment: though it occupies almost the entire screen, it is not maximized.
After calling maximize, it returns 800 though. But it was definitely
not 500 earlier, if I could trust my eyes. May be it picks up some
default setting and is not set correctly until the applicationcomplete event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property width="100%" won't do anything as it is an AIR application and it's default state is not always maximized (at least on my Mac OS). The snippet below automatically maximize the app and trace its bounds and current state whenever you minimize, maximize or restore the window.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication  
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    layout="absolute"
    creationComplete="maximize()"
    displayStateChange="onDisplayStateChange(event)">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            public function onDisplayStateChange(event:NativeWindowDisplayStateEvent):void {
            Alert.show(event.afterDisplayState + ' ' + bounds.toString());
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  `Capabilities.screenResolutionX` and `capabilities.screenResolutionY` to find out screen size.